# How to url encode special character ~ in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to do an url encoding on the following string  the following string 'https://bla/ble:bli~' using the urllib standard library on Python 3.10. Problem is that the ~ character is not encoded to %7E as per
[url encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP). Is there a way around it?

I have tried

```
from urllib.parse import quote

input_string = 'https://bla/ble:bli~'

url_encoded = quote(input_string)
```

url_encoded takes the value 'https%3A//bla/ble%3Abli~'

I have also tried:

```
url_encoded = quote(input_string,safe='~')
```

In this case the url_encoded takes the value 'https%3A%2F%2Fbla%2Fble%3Abli~'

Comment: `~` is an unreserved character. It has no special meaning in URLs, and does not need encoding.

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: @NickSlash 'https%3A//bla/ble%3Abli%7E' or 'https%3A%2F%2Fbla%2Fble%3Abli%7E'

Comment: the `safe` parameter excludes characters from encoding, there is no option to force encoding for specific characters. (using urllib.parse.quote)

Comment: @StamatisTiniakos, I've edited my answer and added a function. Please see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'~' character is not required to be encoded. (Though its encoded formate is %7E). The tilde is one of the allowed characters in url. So you can use any of the followings:

```
from urllib.parse import quote
input_string = 'https://bla/ble:bli~'
url_encoded = quote(input_string)
```

or you can use request module as well

```
import requests
input_string = 'https://bla/ble:bli~'
url_encoded = requests.utils.requote_uri(input_string)
```

Edit: As you are specific about url_encoding for all the special characters, I'm adding the following function. Use the following function:

```
def url_encode(url):

    #add more characters into the list if required
    lst = ['[', '@', '_', '!', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', '<', '>', '?', '/', '\\', '|', '{', '}', '~', ':', ']]']
    for x in url:
        if x in lst:
            new = hex(ord(x)).replace('x', '').upper()
            new = f'%{new}'
            url = url.replace(x, new)
    return url
```

Comment: In my use case I need to encode ~ to %7E

Comment: neither of those modules will encode the `~` so your going to need to make your own, or just `.replace()` on the output of the `quote`

Comment: @StamatisTiniakos What use case do you think requires `~` to be encoded?

Comment: @SuramuthuR thanks for you effort, I used a slightly different approach (see my answer) but I accepted your answer nevertheless.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following solution but the one accepted is also good.

```
def encode_all(string):
    encoded_chars = []
    for char in string:
        if char.isalnum():  # Exclude letters and numbers
            encoded_chars.append(char)
        else:
            encoded_chars.append("%{0:0>2X}".format(ord(char)))
    return "".join(encoded_chars)
```

Comment: There is no "above" or "below"; each viewer sees the answers in accordance with their personal preferences,

Comment: @tripleee noted and corrected.

Comment: If you use `2X` instead of `2x` you wouldn't need the `.upper()`.